# PHP show money_format without currency text

Tags: php, money-format

In PHP, is it possible to use money_format to display money without showing the currency or at least showing it in an abbreviated form?

Currently, I use:

```
$money = "1234.56";
setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE");
$money = money_format("%n", $money);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

!

Seriously. that's the flag:

```
$money = money_format("%!n", $money);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there also a flag to use € instead of EUR??

Comment: `$money = money_format("€ %!n", $money);` works in my environments. Depends on server configuration unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

try number_format($money)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: +1, This is really helpfull instead of money_format.

Comment: Perfect for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// this if for Malaysia  , you can check according to your locality

$number = new NumberFormatter($locale = 'ms_MS.utf8', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    echo $nmuber->format($amount)."\n"; ## 20,00,00,00,000
// if this give error 
Class 'NumberFormatter' not found
// for this  you can do  you can do a
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```