# Format (to currency) php syntax in K2 STORE

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I am customizing k2 store front end and I need some help with currency formatting.

My code is:

```
<span>Tax: <?php echo $item->tax ?></span>
<span>Price without tax: <?php echo $item->price; ?></span>
```

Don't know why but this code outputs:

```
Tax: 11
Price without TAX: 50.00000
```

I would like to output:

```
Tax: 11,00 EUR
Price without tax: 50,00 EUR
```

I found some hints for formatting values in PHP but I was not able to implement it in my case. I have a poor PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

how about using php's [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function? In this case a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519923/php-money-format-for-euro) seems to have an answer

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');
$amount = money_format('%(#1n', $amount);
echo $amount;
```

you could put this into a function like

```
function to_euro($input){
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');
    return money_format('%(#1n', $input);
}
```

then use it like

```
echo to_euro($item->tax);
```